# 'paintComponent()' method is triggered twice

Tags: java, swing

I am currently working on a Snake game, programmed in Java. For some reason, the `paintComponent` method is called twice and I don't understand why that is the case.

```
GamePanelMultiplayer() {
    random = new Random();
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT));
    this.setBackground(Color.black);
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.addKeyListener(new MyKeyAdapter());
    startGame();
}

public void startGame(){
    newApple();
    running = true;
    timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
    timer.start();
}

// sets the coordinates for the new apple.
public void newApple(){
    appleX = random.nextInt(SCREEN_WIDTH/UNIT_SIZE)*UNIT_SIZE;
    appleY = random.nextInt(SCREEN_HEIGHT/UNIT_SIZE)*UNIT_SIZE;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
    draw(g);
}

public void draw(Graphics g){
    System.out.println("Draw has been called");
    if(running) {
        //  drawing the matrix to help visualize the game area
        for(int i=0; i<=SCREEN_HEIGHT/UNIT_SIZE; i++) {
            g.drawLine(i*UNIT_SIZE, 0, i*UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
            g.drawLine(0, i*UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_WIDTH, i*UNIT_SIZE);
        }

        //  drawing the apple
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(appleX, appleY, UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
    }
}
```

I know that the first call to `paintComponent` is triggered by the background change in the constructor function. The second call is made somewhere inside `startGame()`, since after running the program, the apple coordinates are updated, meaning that `paintComponent` is called sometime after `newApple()`.

Thank you for taking some time to help a fellow programmer out ^^!

Comment: You shouldn't care.  `paintComponent` could be called any number of times for any number of reasons.  It's up to the `RepaintManager` to make the decision of when and what should be repainted.  You just need to respond to it (via the `paintComponent` method).  It's unlikely that you component is been painted when it's constructed, as it won't have been attached to a native peer (or realised on the screen).  It's more likely that it's been repainted because it's been added to a container and/or the container is been laid out (ie the components bounds have changed)

Comment: I understand that it's not my job to know when paintComponent is called, I was just wondering how is the apple not on (0,0) and if there is any method inside startGame() that triggers it. Thank you for the response!

Comment: *"I was just wondering how is the apple not on (0,0)"* - Because `newApple` randomise the position, which is called by `startGame` which is called by (I assume) the constructor - remember there is a disconnect between creating a component and adding it to a container and the time the component gets painted - but I'm making a lot of guesses as you've provided an out-of-context code snippet which I'm assuming is all related